# How to allow all ssl serficates in Apache Camel?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel

I use Apache Camel and SOAP, when I tried to connect to **https** endpoint, i got:

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

For connection i use route, like this

```
from(mainJobEndpoint)
            .routeId(sourceName)
            .filter(method(this, "readyToProcess"))
            .process(exchange -> {
                setExtractionProcess(extractionProcessService.startProcess(sourceName));
                ProcessHistory processHistory = processHistoryService.downloadStart(extractionProcess);
                camelContext.getRegistry().bind(sourceName + "downloadStart", processHistory);
                exchange.setProperty("downloadStart", processHistory);
            })
            .process(exchange -> {
                LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();
                GetMessageIdsRequest request = new GetMessageIdsRequest();
                request.setStartDate(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(today.minusDays(100).toString()));
                request.setEndDate(DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(today.minusDays(1).toString()));
                exchange.getIn().setBody(request);
            })
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant(soapOperationGetMessageIds))
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, constant(soapOperationNamespace))
            .setHeader("Content-type", constant(CONTENT_TYPE))
            .to("cxf:bean:cxfBankrupt")
```

And so on

I think that my problem from sertificates. I can't add my custom sertificate. How can i allow all sertificates or disable verification?

Comment: Is the certificate properly configured on the server side? If you really want / need to bypass this, I guess you'd have to instruct the JRE your application runs under to trust all certificates. Have you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ

Comment: Just ignore SSL error, what should go wrong. _facepalm_

Comment: @fábio-carmo-santos, i cheked this link. It doesn't work for me, I don't know why. Maybe because I use Apache Camel

Comment: @paladin, how can I ignore it?

Comment: You should not ignore SSL error.